# Am I using `button.disabled = true;` incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, easeljs, animate-cc

I'm trying to build an interaction in Animate CC that plays movie clips, and the buttons disappear after they are clicked.

I'm trying to disable the other buttons temporarily while the movie clip plays over the main background, but it's not playing nice.

A code Snippet of the click handler:

```
exportRoot.btn_cook.addEventListener("click", cook_clickHandler.bind(this));
function cook_clickHandler(){
    exportRoot.cook.gotoAndPlay(1); //play the info clip
    exportRoot.btn_cook.visible = false; //hide button for no replays
    disableAll();
}
```

`disableAll();` does the following for each button on the canvas:

```
if(exportRoot.btn_receive.visible == true){
    exportRoot.btn_receive.disabled = true;
}
```

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to use this properly. When I run through the interaction, I am still able to click on the buttons, even though I supposedly disabled them?

This demo won't load sound on GitHub, but it works otherwise. [Click here to see it.](https://mhardingfoodsafe.github.io/clickToReveal/)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with this simplified example: http://jsbin.com/wezenom/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Poking at the URL (you must provide a [mcve] in the question itself!) it looks like your buttons are not buttons, so the `disabled` property is meaningless.

Comment: @Quentin it's a large file, and there's supposed to be a few seconds of audio at the beginning, so the buttons are there, they just don't come on the screen for a little bit :) sorry about that. I should have mentioned. I'm not sure why the error is happening. It could be due to it being animate cc. For whatever reason, when I play a movieclip over the buttons, it still lets you click the buttons.

Comment: also, maybe try an image button? these are classified as a button on animate cc, and they have an up state, down state, and over state... so, wouldn't they be buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem so I have another way to do it:

You can try to remove the `eventListener` **click**, like this:

```
if(!exportRoot.btn_receive.hasEventListener("click")){
    exportRoot.btn_receive.removeEventListener("click", cook_clickHandler);
}
```

When u want this to be enabled again, add the `eventListener`.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, because I can't actually find a disabled property in the easeljs documentation. I think I initially used it because javascript does have disabled? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The disabled attribute is a Boolean attribute. That means that just the presence of it is enough to cause the element to become disabled. It makes no difference what you set the value to. You need to remove the attribute from the element to remove the disabled effect.

Removing the event listener treats the symptom, it doesn't get to the heart of the issue.

Also (FYI), the `visibility` property gets values of `"visible"` or `"hidden"`, not `true` or `false`.

Here is a simple example of how to apply and disable (no pun intended) the disabled attribute:

```js
btnToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".disableEnable");
  
  // Loop through each element in the class
  elems.forEach(function(element){
    
    // Check to see if the first element has the disabled attribute
    // the value of the attribute doesn't matter. If the attribute
    // is present, the element is currently disabled.
    if(element.getAttribute("disabled")){
      
      // Element is disabled, so enabled it by removing
      // the attribute (not by setting a value)
      element.removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
      // Element is enabled, so disable it by adding the disabled
      // attribute. Again, the value doesn't matter, but convention
      // says that we set a value of "disabled" to convey that it is
      // a boolean attribute.
      element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
                           
  });
    
});
```

```html
<button id="btnToggle">Disable / Enable</button>

<button class="disableEnable">Test Button</button>
<input class="disableEnable">
<input type="text" class="disableEnable">
```

Comment: Would this still work in animate-cc though? that uses a create-js api, which  seems different from regular javascript. I got the visibility bit from the documentation, here http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html#property_visible